# Vertx http server Thread has been blocked for xxxx ms, time limit is 2000

Tags: java, multithreading, http, vert.x

i have written a large scale http server using , but im getting this error when number of concurrent requests increases

```
 WARNING: Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-1,5,main] has been blocked for 8458 ms, time limit is 1000
```

io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked

here is my full code :

```
  public class MyVertxServer {

public Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx(new VertxOptions().setWorkerPoolSize(100));
private HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer();
private Router router = Router.router(vertx);

public void bind(int port){


    server.requestHandler(router::accept).listen(port);

}

public void createContext(String path,MyHttpHandler handler){

    if(!path.endsWith("/")){
        path += "/";
    }

    path+="*";


    router.route(path).handler(new Handler<RoutingContext>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(RoutingContext ctx) {

            String[] handlerID = ctx.request().uri().split(ctx.currentRoute().getPath());

            String suffix = handlerID.length > 1 ? handlerID[1] : null;
            handler.Handle(ctx, new VertxUtils(), suffix);

        }
    });
}


}
```

and how i call it :

```
    ver.createContext("/getRegisterManager",new ProfilesManager.RegisterHandler());
    ver.createContext("/getLoginManager", new ProfilesManager.LoginHandler());
    ver.createContext("/getMapcomCreator",new ItemsManager.MapcomCreator());
    ver.createContext("/getImagesManager", new ItemsManager.ImagesHandler());

    ver.bind(PORT);
```

how ever i dont find eventbus() useful for http servers that process send/receive files , because u need to send the RoutingContext in the message with is not possible.

could you please point me to the right direction? thanks

added a little bit of handler's code:

```
  class ProfileGetter implements MyHttpHandler{

    @Override
    public void Handle(RoutingContext ctx, VertxUtils utils, String suffix) {

        String username = utils.Decode(ctx.request().headers().get("username"));
        String lang = utils.Decode(ctx.request().headers().get("lang"));

        display("profile requested : "+username);

        Profile profile = ProfileManager.FindProfile(username,lang);

        if(profile == null){
            ctx.request().response().putHeader("available","false");
            utils.sendResponseAndEnd(ctx.response(),400);
            return;
        }else{
            ctx.request().response().putHeader("available","true");
            utils.writeStringAndEnd(ctx, new Gson().toJson(profile));
        }

    }



  }
```

here ProfileManager.FindProfile(username,lang) does a long running database job on the same thread

...

basically all of my processes are happening on the main thread , because if i use executor i will get strange exceptions and nullpointers in Vertx , making me feel like the request proccessors in Vertx are parallel

Comment: Your routing is fine, so I think there's a problem with the handlers implementation. Specifically I suspect that ImagesHandler is doing work on the main thread. Could you please share this code?

Comment: i found out that the single thread being is nature of Vertx . all processes happen on single thread using Eventbus , no idea how is that gonna work for such server , or is that even gonna work at all

Comment: @Reza it will work as long as you rely on asynch APIs. The issue as Alexey Soshin said is not on the router but the code you're running in your handlers.

Comment: well i will add my code there , let see

Comment: but since its single threaded , and so uses only one cpu core (does it?) i dont think its gonna work for me for the long running jobs

Comment: @Paulo Lopes there you go mate ,will really appreciate if you can just show me an example of how to do handle long running jobs in Vertx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the small amount of code in the question lets agree that the problem is on the line:

```
Profile profile = ProfileManager.FindProfile(username,lang);
```

Assuming that this is internally doing some blocking JDBC call which is a anti-pattern in Vert.x you can solve this in several ways.

Say that you can totally refactor the `ProfileManager` class which IMO is the best then you can update it to be reactive, so your code would be like:

```
ProfileManager.FindProfile(username,lang, res -> {
  if (res.failed()) {
    // handle error, sent 500 back, etc...
  } else {
    Profile profile = res.result();

    if(profile == null){
      ctx.request().response().putHeader("available","false");
      utils.sendResponseAndEnd(ctx.response(),400);
      return;
    }else{
      ctx.request().response().putHeader("available","true");
      utils.writeStringAndEnd(ctx, new Gson().toJson(profile));
    }
  }
});
```

Now what would be hapening behind the scenes is that your JDBC call would not block (which is tricky because JDBC is blocking by nature). So to fix this and you're lucky enough to use MySQL or Postgres then you could code your JDBC against the [async-client](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-mysql-postgresql-client/java/) if you're stuck with other RDBMS servers then you need to use the [jdbc-client](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-jdbc-client/java/) which in turn will use a thread pool to offload the work from the event loop thread.

Now say that you cannot change the `ProfileManager` code then you can still off load it to the thread pool by wrapping the code in a `executeBlocking` block:

```
vertx.executeBlocking(future -> {
  Profile profile = ProfileManager.FindProfile(username,lang);
  future.complete(profile);
}, false, res -> {
  if (res.failed()) {
    // handle error, sent 500 back, etc...
  } else {
    Profile profile = res.result();

    if(profile == null){
      ctx.request().response().putHeader("available","false");
      utils.sendResponseAndEnd(ctx.response(),400);
      return;
    }else{
      ctx.request().response().putHeader("available","true");
      utils.writeStringAndEnd(ctx, new Gson().toJson(profile));
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: wait , im not newbie , but if i return answer in a Runnable() , it will still be on the same thread right ? how ever the thread wont be locked any more ? any way i am using HickariCP which is perfect threadpool for mysql , what if i apply both of above methods you mentioned?

Comment: since im mainly android programmer , threads could be a little confusing for me in java

Comment: the jdbc-client deals with connection pools for you and you can choose from several ones including HikariCP see: http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-jdbc-client/java/#_configuration

Comment: thanks for replies mate , i accept your answer since it makes sense , but i will appreciate if you answer my comments too :)

Comment: If you return inside a `Runnable` you still need to run it in a thread, you can hos your own thread pool and but be careful because if you reference objects from different contexts you might get null pointers and this is what `executeBlocking` solves for you. In this case you will have to deal with thread safety, locking, etc... on your own which is something vert.x is trying to solve for you.

Comment: yes noticed , and works great thanks alot mate, except , this executor seems to be parallel , even when i create with vertx.createSharedWorkerExecutor("my-worker-pool",poolSize,maxExecuteTime) , it still runs 1 job at a time , any thing to do about that ?

Comment: That is because the default behavior of `executeBlocking` is serial, in your case you don't care about the order so you should set it to unordered as per in the docs: http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/Vertx.html#executeBlocking-io.vertx.core.Handler-boolean-io.vertx.core.Handler- (i've updated the answer to be parallel)

Comment: you saved me from SO MUCH pain :D , one of reasons is because i love vertx